# Can "sort" function inside of <algorithm> be used to sort 2-dimensional char arrays?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, matrix, char

```
char s[251],c[13][21],*p;
int n;
f.get(s,251);
p=strtok(s," ");
n=0;
while(p)
{
    strcpy(c[n],p);
    ++n;
    p=strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Code takes multiple words separated by spaces then the n word is put on the n-1 line of the "c" char matrix. What the program should do next is sort those words in alphabetical order.

How can I use the "sort" function to do that ? If not are there any other ways to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't `std::sort` `char[][]`s, because arrays are not assignable. You can sort `char*[]`s, because pointers are.

However I suggest that instead of `char[][]` you use `std::vector<std::string>` and sort that, or use `std::set<std::string>` which enforces an alphabetic order on it's elements.

```
std::string line;
f.getline(line);
std::stringstream ss(line);
std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), {});
std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words));
```

Answer (score 4):

No. `std::sort` cannot be used to sort a 2D array, because elements of a 2D array are arrays and arrays are not swappable, which is something that `std::sort` requires.

You could use `std::array` as shown by [Ted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260547/2079303), which may be fine for a small array like yours. But do realise that swapping an array has linear complexity, and therefore sorting array elements can be quite slow for large arrays.

If you wish to sort an array of arrays, it is better to use indirection. Instead of subarrays, use references to arrays. I mean reference in general sense; you cannot have arrays of `T&` references. You can keep your 2D array untouched, but sort an array of pointers to that 2D array:

```
char* rows[std::size(c)];
for(size_t i = 0; i < std::size(c); i++)
    rows[i] = c[i];
}
std::sort(std::begin(rows), std::end(rows), [](char* l, char* r){
    return std::strcmp(l, r) < 0;
});
// rows now contains pointers to each row of c; in sorted order
```

If you wish to have the original array modified instead of a "pointer view", then you should use indirection in the original array itself. For that, you need dynamic allocation, and the simplest solution is `std::string`:

```
std::array<std::string, 13> c;
```

This can be sorted without even a custom comparison object. Note though that the strings in the array are empty, so you must first grow them by for example inserting characters. It is not a drop-in replacement for an array whose elements exist for the entire lifetime of the array.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, no you can't. You can however use `std::array`'s where `std::sort` will do a lexicographical comparison of the inner arrays.

```
std::array<std::array<char, 21>, 13> c;
//...
std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());

for(const auto& v : c)
    std::cout << v.data() << "\n";
```

Note that this is a very slow way of sorting strings since the inner arrays (`std::array<char, 21>`) will be copied around, byte-by-byte, when they need to change places. Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: This answer is entirely correct. But might want to mention that sorting `std::array` elements can be quite slow.

Comment: The natural comparison for `std::array<char, N>` will include any junk stored after the end of a *char array* style string. So that could be an issue.

Comment: To fix problem pointed out by @Galik: Value-initialise `c` so that the *junk* is just null-terminators.

Comment: The `strcpy` will place a `\0` after the interesting char's, so it shouldn't matter what the rest is in a lexicographical comparison, should it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo lexicographical comparison does not stop at `'\0'`. Another fix is to use `std::strcmp` like I show in my pointer suggestion.

Comment: @eerorika regarding it being slow: Won't it just swap the inner arrays (their internal pointers) when they need to change place?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::array` contains just an array. It has no "internal pointer".

Comment: @eerorika Ok, very slow then indeed.

Comment: @eerorika Value initializing will only work for the first string stored in the array. If it is later modified then the problem returns. Value initialization can sometimes mask problems like that.

Comment: @Galik yes. One needs to not make assumptions when dealing with arrays of characters.

Comment: @eerorika I think the point that Ted is making is that 0 is less than any other char, so the junk afterwards only participates in the ordering of "equal" strings. It would be a problem for `std::stable_sort`

Comment: @Caleth fair enough. How about reading indeterminate values; Is that not a problem?

Comment: @eerorika Yes, at least the `std::cout << v.data()` part will result in UB unless all inner arrays are null terminated - which is something I doubt very much when looking at OP:s code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo We're assuming that the strings are null terminated. My point is that the comparison algorithm does not stop at null terminator, and keeps comparing until the first character that differs up to the end of the array. And if those compared characters have indeterminate value, then the behaviour of the program would be undefined. (Unless there is an exception for reading indeterminate `char`. I'm not sure if that's the case).

Comment: @eerorika I think I understand what you are asking. Does `char foo[3]; strcpy(foo, "a"); char ch = foo[2]; ...` result in UB or not?  If `foo` is global (or static or thread local), it should be zero initialized and therefor ok. Otherwise it's UB. Only `unsigned char` and `std::byte` are exempted if I understand it correctly.